# tr(ab) = tr(ba)?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, traces

It is well known that given two Hilbert-Schmidt operators $a$ and $b$ on a Hilbert space $H$, their product is trace class and $tr(ab)=tr(ba)$. A similar result holds for $a$ bounded and $b$ trace class.

The following attractive statement, however, is false:

**Non-theorem**:
*Let $a$ and $b$ be bounded operators on $H$. If $ab$ is trace class , then $ba$ is trace class and $tr(ab)=tr(ba)$.*

The counterexample is $a=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}\otimes 1_{\ell^2(\mathbb N)}$, $b=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}\otimes 1_{\ell^2(\mathbb N)}$.

I'm guessing that the following is also false, but I can't find a counterexample:

**Non-theorem?**:
*Let $a$ and $b$ be two bounded operators on $H$. If $ab$ and $ba$ are trace class, then  $tr(ab)=tr(ba)$.*

Comment: Here's a link to Bill Johnson's followup question in Banach spaces http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76604

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**EDIT:** Bill Johnson has pointed out a gap in my initial answer. It seems that bridging this gap is just as difficult as proving that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. Below I give two other proofs of this equality. The flawed proof is also reproduced at the end.

**Proof 1** (alluded to by Bill in his comment to Gjergji's answer): It's well-known that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues (with the same multiplicities). Lidskii's trace formula then implies that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. QED.

**Proof 2**: This proof doesn't use Lidskii's formula. It's taken from

> Laurie, Nordgren, Radjavi,  Rosenthal, *On triangularization of algebras of operators.* Reine Angew. Math. **327** (1981), 143–155.

We'll need to rely on the fact that $tr(ST)=tr(TS)$ if one of $S$ and $T$ is trace class.

Let $A=UP$ be the polar decomposition of $A$. Then $PB=U^\ast AB$ is trace class. But then one knows that $tr(UPB)=tr(PBU)$. So it suffices to prove that $tr(PBU)=tr(BUP)$. Therefore, we might as well assume that $A$ is positive. In this case we can let $P_n$ denote the spectral projection of $A$ onto $[1/n,\|A\|]$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} tr(P_nAB) = tr(AB)$. Now, for $T$ trace class $Q$ a projection we have $tr(QT)=tr(QTQ)=tr(TQ)$, whence $tr(P_n AB) = tr(P_n A P_n B P_n)$ since $P_n$ and $A$ commute. But the contraction $P_n B P_n$ of $B$ is trace class, for $P_n AB$ is trace class and the restriction of $P_n A$ to the range of $P_n$ is invertible. Thus $tr(P_n A P_n B P_n) = tr(P_n B P_n A) = tr(BA P_n)$ and consequently
$$ tr(AB) = \lim_{n\to\infty} tr(P_n AB) = \lim_{n\to\infty} tr(BAP_n) = tr(BA), $$
as desired.

---

Finally, here is the flawed proof.

> Let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Then
>   $$ tr(AB) = \sum_i \langle ABe_i, e_i \rangle = \sum_i \langle Be_i, A^\ast e_i \rangle. $$
>   But $\langle Be_i,A^\ast e_i \rangle = \sum_j \langle Be_i, e_j\rangle \overline{\langle A^\ast e_i, e_j\rangle}$, and therefore
>   $$\begin{align}
> tr(AB) &= \sum_i \sum_j \langle Be_i, e_j\rangle \overline{\langle A^\ast e_i, e_j\rangle} \\
> &= \sum_i \sum_j \overline{\langle B^\ast e_j, e_i\rangle} \langle A e_j, e_i \rangle \\
> &= \sum_j \sum_i \overline{\langle B^\ast e_j, e_i\rangle} \langle A e_j, e_i \rangle \qquad (???) \\
> &= \sum_j \langle Ae_j, B^\ast e_j \rangle \\
> &= \sum_j \langle BAe_j, e_j \rangle \\
> &= tr(BA).
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Why is the change of order of summation OK?  

Comment: @Bill Johnson, that's where Faisal is using that ab and ba are both trace class, I think.

Comment: I assumed as much, Gjergi, but I don't see a proof, hence my question. 

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, it's not clear why the order of summation is interchangeable. The proof I used to convince myself that the double sum was absolutely convergent is flawed. Thanks for pointing this out, Bill. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 20):

This follows from proposition 7.3 in ["Trace-class operators and commutators"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123689900645) by N.J. Kalton. The theorem actually proves something stronger, that for $AB-BA$, if you arrange the eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicity so that $|\lambda_n|\geq |\lambda_{n+1}|$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_{n}}{n}<\infty$$
which implies trace zero, but the converse is false.

Comment: For a more difficult proof, quote Lidskii's trace formula (the trace of a trace class operator is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues).