# tr(ab)=tr(ba), part 2.

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is a Banach space version of Andre Henriques' question

[Trace Question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76386/trab-trba)

for Hilbert spaces.  Let $a:X\to Y$ and $b:Y\to X$ be bounded linear operators between Banach spaces s.t. $ba$ and $ab$ are both nuclear.  Assume whatever approximation properties on $X$ and $Y$ that you want (say, assume that both $X^*$ and $Y^*$ have the bounded or even metric approximation property), so that the trace of $ab$ and of $ba$ are well defined.  Then must $tr(ab)=tr(ba)$?

When $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces, you can find three correct proofs and one interesting but incomplete proof at the above link.  None of these generalize immediately to the Banach space setting.

Caveat:  I have not done a literature search or thought much about this problem, but it is natural to consider it after reading Andre's question.

Comment: If finite-dimensionality is an allowable approximation property, then I know a very elementary proof...

Comment: @Mark Meckes: As a student I found the result as well as the fact that the trace is well defined mysterious.  Other students laughed at me, but later, after reading Grothendieck's Memoirs, I realized that I was right. 

As for a simple proof in finite dimensions, the flawed proof in the link works and is not too bad.



Comment: I tried to use approximation properties to reduce to the finite dimensional case, but was not successful. It would be enough to prove that is $ab$ is nuclear and $T_n$ is bounded and tends strongly to the identity on the range space of $b$ and `$$T_n$` tends strongly to the identity on the range space of `$b^*$`, then $tr(aT_n b)$ converges to $tr(ab)$.

Comment: I thought about similar things in my thesis-- the only reference I could find was M. Grosser, "The trace of certain commutators", Rev. Roumaine Math. Pures Appl. 34 (1989), no. 5, 413–418.  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1021948  This imposes strong conditions on $a$ and $b$ (but the proof is much too complicated, I give an easy, half-page proof in my thesis).  So I suspect that the general case might be hard...

Comment: @Bill: the flawed proof in the link is of course the elementary one I had in mind for finite dimensions.  But I agree with you that the trace is more mysterious than is often recognized.  Are you familiar with the textbook "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler?  He *defines* the trace of an operator on a finite-dimensional space to be the sum of its eigenvalues, and only after that proves that it can be calculated by summing diagonal matrix entries.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  Would you please send me that page from your thesis?

Comment: Hmmm.  Sheldon's definition is not a good one because Lidskii is badly wrong in infinite dimensions except for certain spaces that are very close to Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Fair enough, but I still like it better than the usual elementary definition in terms of matrices.  Axler's definition is elementary enough for an undergrad linear algebra class, it is manifestly basis-independent, it's easy to believe from the definition that it's an important and useful quantity, and it generalizes (albeit with work) to Hilbert spaces.  I'm not sure I know any other definition meets all those criteria.  Of course, if you'd rather drop any of those criteria in favor of getting a definition that generalizes better to Banach spaces, that's understandable.

Comment: But introducing a seemingly non linear functional to a linear algebra class is a bit strange. 

Comment: Yes, motivation is an issue, but I think no more so than with the usual definition.

Comment: @Bill, where in Grothendieck's Memoirs were your suspicions of mysteriousness of the trace confirmed?

Comment: That the trace of the zero operator is not well defined on a space that fails the approximation property. That is, if $X$ fails the approximation property, then there are a sequence $f_n$ in `$X^*$` and $x_n$ in $X$ s.t. $\sup \|f_n\| <\infty$, $\sum \|x_n\| = 1$, 
$\sum f_n(x_n) = 1$, yet $\sum f_n(x) x_n = 0$ for all $x$ in $X$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My question has a negative answer.

**Lemma.** Suppose $X$ has the approximation property (AP), $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, and $X/Y$ fails the AP.  Then there is a nuclear operator $T$ on $X$ s.t. $TX\subset Y$, $T^2=0$, and $tr(T)=1$.

Suppose you have $X$, $Y$, $T$ as in the lemma and $Y$ has the AP.  Define $a:X\to Y$ to be $T$ considered as an operator into $Y$ and let $b:Y\to X$ be the inclusion map.  Then $ba=T$ has trace one but $ab=0$.

Experts will see immediately that you can realize the situation in the previous paragraph by letting $Z$ be a James-Lindenstrauss space s.t. $Z^{**}/Z$ fails the AP while $Z^{**}$ and $Z$ have Schauder bases.  More remarkable is that you can even have $X=\ell_p$ with $1<p<2$ and $Y$ isomorphic to $\ell_p$.  This was proved by A. Szankowski a couple of years ago.

The lemma is easy:  Since  $X/Y$ fails the AP, by Grothendieck's classical characterization of the AP there is an absolutely summable sequence $f_n$ in $(X/Y)^*$ and a sequence $z_n$ in the open unit ball of $X/Y$ s.t. for all $z\in X/Y$, $\sum \langle f_n, z \rangle z_n=0$ but $\sum \langle f_n, z_n \rangle =1$ (that is, the trace of the zero operator on $X/Y$ is not well defined). Let $Q$ be the quotient mapping from $X$ onto $X/Y$ and get $x_n$ in the unit ball of $X$ s.t. $Qx_n=z_n$.  Define a nuclear operator $T$ on $X$ by

$Tx = \sum Q^*f_n(x) x_n$.

$QT=0$ because $\sum \langle f_n, z \rangle z_n=0$ for all $z\in X/Y$ and hence $TX \subset Y$.

$T_{|Y} =$ because $Q^*$ ranges in the annihilator of $Y$ in $X^*$ and hence   $T^2=0$.

Finally, $tr(T)= \sum \langle Q^*f_n, x_n \rangle =\sum \langle f_n, z_n \rangle =0$.

This construction raises more questions than it answers.  For what Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ is there an affirmative answer to the trace question?  The only positive result I see is when one of the spaces is a Hilbert space and the other one is a weak Hilbert space in the sense of Pisier.  The affirmative answer follows because Pisier proved that the Lidskii trace formula is valid for nuclear operators on a weak Hilbert space whose eigenvalues are absolutely summable (an old result due to Konig, Maurey, Retherford and me says that on any Banach space that is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space, there is a nuclear operator whose eigenvalues are not summable, so it is not clear that the trace question has an affirmative answer when $X$ and $Y$ are both weak Hilbert spaces).

ADDED 10/24/11: The paper of Szankowski I mentioned is

Szankowski A (2009)
Three-space problems for the approximation property.
J. Eur. Math. Soc., 11(2): 273-282.

Although obvious, I should have mentioned that from the negative answer to the question for $X=Y=\ell_p$, $1<p<2$, by duality you also get a negative answer for $X=Y=\ell_p$, $2<p<\infty$.