# trace of a commutator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Can one give an example of two bounded operators A and B in a Hilbert space such that both products AB and BA are of the trace class but their traces are different? If one of them is compact then the traces are equal; if one requires the commutator [A,B] to be of the trace class, not each product separately then the left shift and the right shift give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

[tr(ab) = tr(ba)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76386/trab-trba)

and

[tr(ab)=tr(ba), part 2.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76604/trab-trba-part-2)

for the Banach space version.